# Why is this happening in IE7?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

Calling all cross-compatibility experts!

Please check out this page on my site, as it is driving me mad: http://utilitiessavings.co.uk/business-energy/business-electricity/

The orange icon is floated to the left of the orange text on all browsers, except older versions of IE, on which the text is pushed down to a new line.

Can anyone think of a reason why? I've tried everything I can think of.

Thanks

Comment: Just thought it might be worth mentioning that IE8 users need to put on compatibility mode, but you all knew that :)

Comment: On my IE7, it seems nice (not the same vertical alignment but nothing shocking. Anyway, the balls on the bottom on the page aren't aligned for me. Totally on another point, in your form_main.js `groups: {username: "salutation first_name last_name",},` make an error on IE7 : remove the comma after the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing with IE8 in IE7 Mode, if I move the offending image inside the `<div id="rightdiv">`, it looks correct. If I do the same change in Firefox, it still looks the same.

So this seems to be a solution to the problem. As for why it isn't working in IE7 as it was, I'm not sure.

Edit: So, I forgot to write half of the solution: I also added something like `style="padding:5px;margin:0 0 6px 0"` to the `h2`